# MonoTouch get location & capture map image like contacts

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios, location, contacts

As the title, I'm confused with how to capture maps with MonoTouch, and how to get the location. As step by:

```
CLLocationManager locationManager = new CLLocationManager ();
locationManager.UpdatedLocation += UpdatedLocationEvent;
locationManager.Delegate = new MyLocationDelegate ();

locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation ();

    class MyLocationDelegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    public MyLocationDelegate () : base()
    {
    }

    public override void UpdatedLocation (CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation newLocation, CLLocation oldLocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("newLocation  " + newLocation.VerticalAccuracy + "    " + newLocation.HorizontalAccuracy);
        Console.WriteLine ("oldLocation  " + oldLocation.VerticalAccuracy + "    " + oldLocation.HorizontalAccuracy);
    }

    public override void Failed (CLLocationManager manager, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Failed to find location");
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: You need to explain "doesn't work".  Does it crash?  Do you get any errors?  What is or isn't happening?  You should probably be using the Coordinate property of CLLocation instead or Horizontal/Vertical Accuracy.

Comment: No crash, no errors, but not working, I can't get current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not configured the kind of events that you get, you are missing a line like this:

```
locationManager = new CLLocationManager () {
    DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyBest,
    Delegate = new MyCLLocationManagerDelegate (callback),
    DistanceFilter = 1000f
};
if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
    locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation ();
```